# Fair three-way sandwich division

Tags: game-theory, fair-division

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637728/splitting-a-sandwich-and-not-feeling-deceived) discusses fair three-way sandwich division. Mentoined solutions include 
the [Selfridge–Conway discrete procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfridge%E2%80%93Conway_discrete_procedure) and the [moving-knife procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-knife_procedure). I posed the question to the guys at the office and we can't think why this method would not be a solution:

1. A makes the first cut.
2. B makes the second cut.
3. C chooses a piece.
4. A chooses a piece.
5. B gets the remaining piece.

Is this a solution? If not then why not?

Comment: If $A$ cuts the cake / sandwitch / whatever in more or less exactly half, then no matter what B cuts, he will end up with at most a quarter, and thus be unstatisfied.

Comment: But A would have no motivation to cut in half because he will then always be left with less than a third.

Comment: You might say that, but the _point_ of the Selfridge-conway procedure is that _no matter_ where you or anyone else actually cut, as long as you are under the impression that your _own_ cuts are made fairly, and you always _choose_ the biggest piece available, then it logically follows that your share is at least as big as anyone else's. That is not the case in the above procedure.

Comment: Can you state the question in mathematical language?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that A thinks that he has cut the sandwich into 1/3 and 2/3, but B then cuts the piece which A thought was 1/3. C can now take the piece which A thinks is 2/3, and A is going to be very unhappy.