# Thoughts about a how to share a cake

Tags: game-theory, fair-division

So when i was a kid we used to do this thing when we shared a snack. one kid would cut the snack in half and the other would pick which of the two halfs he wants. this way, even though the picker will always have a slight edge, the cut would be pretty fair.

I thought about generalizing this for cakes and for a lot of people.
My intuition is:

> 1. let the first two kids do the "cut and pick" routine.
> 2. each kid will get a half of the cake.
> 3. the two kids will repeat this routine with two new kids for their respective pieces.
> 4. repeat this process until all kids have their own peice

I see two big problems with this method. One, is that this will only work for $2^n$ kids. The other is that because "pickers" have a slight edge, and one kid is guaranteed to "descend" from a line of pickers, this edge will become significant with a lot of kids and he will have a big advantage.

**What would be a better way of doing this?**

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637728/splitting-a-sandwich-and-not-feeling-deceived?rq=1) which treats the "3 kids" case contains a lot of discussion on this topic and may be worth looking at.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/For_All_Practical_Purposes/ehlk3RCQXg4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover    I taught this book one semester, quite good. Later I viewed one or more of the videotapes that go with it, impressive.

Comment: Cut the cake into $2\times 2=4$ pieces using the “cut and pick”method twice. Give each of the three kids $1/4$ of the cake and throw the remaining $1/4$ of the cake in the bin.